# How to force jQuery dropdowns to full width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I've created a jQuery dropdown menu that shows DIVs on hover, but I cannot force the dropdown DIVs to have a 100% width across the page.

**CSS:**

```
ul.oe_menu div{
   position:absolute;
   top:103px;
   left:1px;
   background:#fff;
   width:200; /* This sets the width of the dropdown DIV */
   height:210px;
   padding:30px;
   display:none;
}
```

Take a look at the **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6BEE/2/)** to view the full code & expand the preview section to see the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: what does this `width:200;` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because if you set the div's width 100%, it is taking the 100% of its parent's width (the corresponding `li`).

One solution for this is to set the div's position `fixed` so that it takes the width of the page when its width is set 100%.

```
ul.oe_menu div{
   position:fixed;
   top:103px;
   left:0px;
   background:#fff;
   width:100%;
   height:210px;
   display:none;
}
```

This way you will have to remove the `left:n` from the `div`s. [JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L6BEE/3/).

To make the transition look more natural, you can consider doing `.slideUp(200)` [[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L6BEE/4/)] or `.animate({"opacity":0},{complete:function(){$(this).css("opacity","1")}});` [[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L6BEE/5/)] as`mouseleave`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the div width to the width of the window; (given that you're hiding overflow-x on the body anyway).

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();           
$this.children('div').css({zIndex:'9999',width:winWidth}).stop(true,true)....
```

Have a look here to see;

http://jsfiddle.net/cs3p5/